# How would I display the values of a selected column in Python array?

Tags: python

How would I find the values from a certain column in an array? For example I have:

```
[1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 7, 1, 7, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1]
[7, 4, 5, 1, 8, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4]
[1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 5]
[9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9, 8]
[7, 4, 2, 1, 8, 2, 2, 2, 9, 7]
[7, 4, 2, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 9, 1, 0, 9]
[0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9, 7, 7, 7]
```

If I wanted to list all of the values of column 5, how would I do this? I have figured out how to do this for the rows, but for the columns it is tricky, since they are all part of a separate list. I have not been able to find anything about this and I am very new to Python so I don't really know what I don't know.

Comment: A code golf answer: `list(zip(*list_2d))[4]`

Comment: An actual answer: use a list comprehension. `[x[4] for x in list_2d]`

Comment: This super works! Thank you! Just so I understand this better, what exactly is that function doing?

Comment: The first is a neat transposition trick. The second is a straightforward list comp iteration over each sublist.

Comment: Ok so if I wanted to display the value of a certain cell, would I apply the same sort of rule?

Comment: Certain cell, you'd need the row index `i` and the column index `j`, and just index: `list_2d[i][j]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Just use `l[i][4]` to print 5th column value.

```
l = [
            [1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 7, 1, 7, 6, 9],
            [1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1],
            [7, 4, 5, 1, 8, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4],
            [1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 5],
            [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9, 8],
            [7, 4, 2, 1, 8, 2, 2, 2, 9, 7],
            [7, 4, 2, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5],
            [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 9, 1, 0, 9],
            [0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9, 7, 7, 7]
        ]

for i in l:
    print(i[4])

# or simply use

[i[4] for i in l] #as pointed out by @COLDSPEED

# the above code will create a list with values from 5th column
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/FamousOverdueDehardwarization)

Answer (score 0):

For a two dimensional array, you can use `array[row][column]`.

Comment: He wants to display a complete column and not a single element

Comment: for i in range(len(list)): print list[0][i] for the first column